# How to implement DI using Unity on a class which has a constructor - mvc?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

suppose i have a interface and class like this

```
public interface ILienholderBusinessService
    {
        string GetCoverage(IList<PolicyVinRequest> InputList);
    }

public class LienholderBusinessService : ILienholderBusinessService
    {
        public ILienholderPolicySearchDataService LienholderPolicySearchDataService { get; set; }

        public LienholderBusinessService(ILienholderPolicySearchDataService  LienholderPolicySearchDataService )
        {
            this.LienholderPolicySearchDataService =LienholderPolicySearchDataService ;
        }
        public string GetCoverage(IList<PolicyVinRequest> InputList)
        {
            return "my string";

        }
    }
```

I have a controller like this

```
 public class InsuranceVerificationPortalController : Controller
    {
        public ILienholderBusinessService LienholderBusinessService { get; set; }
        public InsuranceVerificationPortalController(ILienholderBusinessService LienholderBusinessService)
        {
            this.LienholderBusinessService = LienholderBusinessService;
        }
}
```

now when i try to implement unity in my MVC, i get error like

> are you missing any type

How can i implement DI using Unity on a class which has a constructor

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to register mappings for all interfaces that you need to resolve concrete types for.  From the posted code this would be `ILienholderBusinessService` and `ILienholderPolicySearchDataService`:

```
container.RegisterType<ILienholderBusinessService, LienholderBusinessService>();
container.RegisterType<ILienholderPolicySearchDataService, LienholderPolicySearchDataService>();
```

It could be that the implementation of `ILienholderPolicySearchDataService` also depends on interfaces/abstract classes (e.g. `IRepository<T>`).  If that is the case then mappings will need to be created for those as well.

By default, Unity will select the constructor with the most number of parameters so if you need to choose another constructor you can use an  `InjectionConstructor`.  e.g.

```
container.RegisterType<ILienholderPolicySearchDataService, LienholderPolicySearchDataService>(
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IRepository<Policy>)));
```